# Download image from s3 in mobile device from google chrome not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, image, amazon-s3

So I got this project in React - I'm pulling images from S3 storage, displaying them and allowing user to download them.
For the download action I'm fetching the image (from my NodeJS server, security reasons) and returning base64 string to the client.

```
let image = await axios.get(img, {responseType: 'arraybuffer'});
let returnedB64 = Buffer.from(image.data).toString('base64');
return returnedB64;
```

On client side (to download the image) I'm doing -

```
var a = document.createElement("a"); //Create <a>
a.href = "data:image/png;base64," + data; //Image Base64 Goes here, data is the base64 string returned from server
a.download = `name-${someName}.jpg`; //File name Here
a.target = `_blank`; 
a.click(); //Downloaded file
```

In desktop (chrome, safari and so) it works great.
In mobile devices (safari) it also works good, but when I use chrome - it fails.
(on several devices it just throws error, and sometimes the download get executed - but when you open the file it's just an empty document without any content.
I tried a lot of methods of download (used libraries like - file-saver, downloadjs and so) but none of them fixed the problem.
I did a lot of research about it and didn't find any solution.